# How to install TensorFlow on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tensorflow

I'm trying to install tensorflow library by using de command:

```
> pip install tensorflow
```

I already have the latest version of python (3.8.0), but I'm getting the next error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Distributed binaries of TensorFlow currently do not support Python 3.8, you should use version 3.5, 3.6 or 3.7.

Comment: Thank you @jdehesa, that was the problem, I installed python 3.6.8 and done.

Answer (score 0):

Now Tensorflow supports Python 3.8
install Tensorflow using

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Follow the instructions mentioned in the [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows) website.